# how to list all NPM package and its version available in azure feed?

Tags: azure, npm, feed

I have requested to list out all the NPM packages available in the Azure Artifact location.

Able to list from project scoped feed and unable to list NPM packages from Organization scoped feeds. Please help

Answer (score 0):

- As per this [MSDoc -  Get Packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifacts/artifact-details/get-packages?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

To list out all the packages available in the Azure Artifact location, use the below REST API

```cs
GET https://feeds.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/packaging/Feeds/{feedId}/packages?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

- As per this [MSDoc -  Get Package Versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifacts/artifact-details/get-package-version?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

To get the list of Package Versions, use the below API

```cs
GET https://feeds.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/packaging/Feeds/{feedId}/Packages/{packageId}/versions/{packageVersionId}?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

- To get the list of `npm packages` Version, use

```cs
GET https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/packaging/feeds/{feedId}/npm/{packageName}/versions/{packageVersion}?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

Please refer [Artifacts -  Npm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifactspackagetypes/npm?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) for more information

Answer (score 0):

Below PowerShell script helped me to pull the list using PAT.

function GetUrl() {
param(
[string]$orgUrl,
[hashtable]$header,
[string]$AreaId
)

```
# Area ids
# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/work-with-urls?view=azure-devops&tabs=http&viewFallbackFrom=vsts#resource-area-ids-reference
# Build the URL for calling the org-level Resource Areas REST API for the RM APIs
$orgResourceAreasUrl = [string]::Format("{0}/_apis/resourceAreas/{1}?api-preview=5.0-preview.1", $orgUrl, $AreaId)

# Do a GET on this URL (this returns an object with a "locationUrl" field)
$results = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $orgResourceAreasUrl -Headers $header

# The "locationUrl" field reflects the correct base URL for RM REST API calls
if ("null" -eq $results) {
    $areaUrl = $orgUrl
}
else {
    $areaUrl = $results.locationUrl
}

return $areaUrl
```

}

$orgUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/myorg"
$personalToken = "mytoken"

Write-Host "Initialize authentication context" -ForegroundColor Yellow
$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($personalToken)"))
$header = @{authorization = "Basic $token"}

## DEMO 1 List of projects

Write-Host "Project List"
#packaging ID refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/work-with-urls?view=azure-devops&tabs=http&viewFallbackFrom=vsts
$coreAreaId = "7ab4e64e-c4d8-4f50-ae73-5ef2e21642a5"
$tfsBaseUrl = GetUrl -orgUrl $orgUrl -header $header -AreaId $coreAreaId

## https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/projects/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

## project name should be specified for project based feed

#$projectsUrl = "$($tfsBaseUrl)Project/_apis/packaging/Feeds/{FeedName}/packages?api-version=6.0-preview.1"
#$projectsUrl = "$($tfsBaseUrl)/_apis/packaging/Feeds/platform-template/packages?includeAllVersions=True&api-version=6.0-preview.1"

## No project name should be specified for Organization based feed

$projectsUrl = "$($tfsBaseUrl)/_apis/packaging/Feeds/{FeedName}/packages?api-version=6.0-preview.1"
$projects = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $projectsUrl -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $header

$projects.value | ForEach-Object {
write-output "Package Name:" $*.name  | Out-File "D:\File.txt" -Append
$projects2Url = "https://feeds.dev.azure.com/pdidev/*apis/packaging/Feeds/{FeedName}/Packages/$($*.id)/versions?api-version=6.0-preview.1"
$project2s = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $projects2Url -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $header
$project2s.value | ForEach-Object {
write-output $*.version `n| Out-File "D:\file.txt" -Append
}
}

Comment: Your answer could be improved by better formatting and additional details regarding your approach. You can find information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).